# Jquery hide element based on given value

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I need to loop through some values and then hide a div that has an id.

To simply here is a piece of code:

```
 var value = 'div1';
  $('#div1).hide();
```

what I like to do is to do something like:

```
 value.hide();
```

Meaning, pass what the value is and then hide it dynamically on document.ready().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like below,

```
  var value = 'div1';
  $('#' + value).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

> what I like to do is to do something like:
>
> value.hide();

```
var value = $("#div1");
value.hide();
```

or

```
var value = 'div1';
$('[id="' + value + '"]').hide();​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or what Vega said :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable like a string http://jsfiddle.net/
​

```
var value = 'div1';
$('#' + value).fadeOut(1000); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
var value = 'div#div1';
$(value).hide();
```